# Titanium assets structuring android

Tags: titanium, titanium-mobile, titanium-modules, titanium-alloy

Am using Titanium 3.1.3.GA, alloys and Emulator 4.1.2 to run my app. As I explore into assets of Android, it has 10 folders like long, notlong, portrait, lanscape,  but normally we use LDPI, MDPI, HDPI, XHDPI. So here images are in what ratio and in what ratio I should fill images in folder with. If am generating app for android, I need to fill all the folders in assets with proper ratio of the same image and whats the ratio used in Appcelerator. May be a novice or stupid question, but needs a clear answer for it to start with. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The clear answer for it was demonstrated by Malcolm in Titanium Appcelerator forum which was created by myself out there, references

http://developer.appcelerator.com/question/157890/images-in-android-drawables#269443

[images in android](http://developer.appcelerator.com/question/149743/images-in-android#answer-258910)

[Same layout for android and iphone](http://developer.appcelerator.com/question/148337/how-to-achieve-same-layout-for-android-and-iphone-using-titanium#answer-256884)

Comment: Can also refer [this](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/latest/#!/guide/Using_density-specific_resources_on_Android) docs.Thank you.